# cucumber should see button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a form that has this

`<%= submit_tag 'Search Event' %>`

and a cucumber step that says

`And I should see "Search Event"`

but this step fails.. why is that?

Here is the error i get

```
expected #has_content?("Search Event") to return true, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Comment: what error does it print out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this doesn't work because the button label is not text content -- it's the value attribute of the submit button.

Comment: i thought so. what is the best way to check for existence of a button?

Comment: You can do this by writing your own step that uses Webrat (or Capybara) to find the button. Or, instead of checking for the existence of a button, you can just (try to) use the button with "Then I press..." to submit the form and confirm the results.

Answer (score 13):

Write your own step, i.e. using capybara (rspec as well):

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" button/ do |name|
  find_button(name).should_not be_nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This work in positive:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" button/ do |name|
  should have_button name
end
```

in negative:

```
Then /^I should not see "([^"]*)" button/ do |name|
  should have_no_button name
end
```